# Medir tiempo gastado por una función

Tags: javascript

Quiero medir el tiempo que  tarda en ejecutarse una función en `js`. Estoy trabajando con la librería `shinysense` de `R` que trabaja con `js` para obtener una imagen desde una webcam. En `R` puedo medir el tiempo que trascurre con la función `system.time` y quisiera ver si hay alguna manera de verlo en `js`.

Pienso que cualquier función de `js` podría funcionar como ejemplo sin embargo adjunto la función en particular que quisiera medir.

```
shutter.on('click', function(){

  if(is_shiny_app){
    shutter.text(shutter_text.taking);
  }     

  // Append a snapshot of video canvas element context        
  photo_holder
    .getContext('2d')
    .drawImage(video_element, 0, 0, image_size.width, image_size.height);
  
  // Grab photo data as a dataurl
  const photo_data = photo_holder.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

  // Send to shiny if needed.
  if(is_shiny_app){
    Shiny.onInputChange(shiny_message_loc, photo_data);
  }    
});
```

Comment: Puedes obtener la hora al inicio y al final, la diferencia es lo que tardó la funcion supongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar Date.now() tiene la limitación de trabajar con milisegundos y de no actualizarse con total precisión, por lo que para "microbenchmarks" se recomienda usar el API [Performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Performance), en este caso te valdría con el método `performance.now()`, que permite trabajar hasta con microsegundos con cierta fiabilidad. Sólo tienes que guardar el tiempo antes de iniciar el proceso, el tiempo al final, y restar los valores:

```js
let array= [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,10,11,13,15,67,4,81,211,4]

let start = performance.now();
array.sort((a,b) => a-b);
let end=performance.now();

console.log('Tiempo empleado:',(end - start),'milisegundos')
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Funcionó muy bien!

Answer (score 2):

El código para medir el tiempo que tomó correr una función sería algo como el siguiente.

```
const inicio = Date.now();
const log = (v) => console.log(`${v} \n Transcurrio: ${Date.now() - inicio}ms`);
```

con ello *inicio* sería el tiempo antes de iniciar la función y luego dentro del log correría un segundo *Date.now()* que este último *(log)* lo correrías al finalizar tu función.

```
log(`inicio de función`);
función()
log(`he terminado la función`);
```

y deberías de tener un resultado de cuántos MS tomó en correr en la consola.

Comment: Buena respuesta! También funcionó.